# nested foreach loop array resets

Tags: php, foreach

how do I stop nested foreach loops from resetting the internal array pointer
for example

```
foreach ($example as $example2)
{
foreach ($xample as $xample2);
{
}
}
```

so for example if, $example & $xample contained the array (1,2,3)

i want to do something like this

```
foreach ($example as $example2)
{
do something with array[1]
foreach ($xample as $xample2);
{
do something else with array[1]
}
}
```

then go on to 2,3 ect...
hope my question is clear because from what i understand is the internal array pointer is being reset during the 2nd loop https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

EDIT
so this is what is happening right now
say $example contains the following values 1,2,3 & $xample contains the same values

```
foreach ($example as $example2)
{
echo ($example2)
foreach $xample as xample2)
{
echo ($xample2)
}
}
```

the output looks something like this, first loop outputs 1,2,3, the 2nd loop just outputs 1,1,1
what I want is to have, first loop 1,2,3 2nd loop 1,2,3

EDIT 2
code is pasted here http://codepad.org/r1py8HR5
the output shows that there are 5 $examples & 7 $xample being echoed
and &xample contains the same $fname2 7 times

Comment: What do you mean by array[1]?

Comment: i mean if array[some value 1, some value 2,] ect.

Comment: You can create a simple working example at http://codepad.org/ if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Each array has its own array pointer. So nesting your `foreach` loops does not require any precautions on your side, it will work just like you coded it.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your edit, I think your error is somewhere else. I recreated your example and it seems to work as you would like (see http://codepad.org/nJrZqCoO).

Comment: foreach works on a copy of the given array. So your example would work for someone who's knowing what he's doing ;)

Comment: @Sloede the only thing that i can think of that might be causing the error is i am building another variable with it, like this  $url = "http://mysite/".$xample2.""

Comment: I don't think that this can be the problem, unless you change the arrays over which you iterate in the `foreach` loop from within the loop (i.e. modifying `$example` or `$xample`)

Comment: @Sloede  here is my code http://codepad.org/r1py8HR5, the output i get is show in the edit

Comment: Please create a minimum working example of your code that can actually be executed, and which produces the unwanted behavior that you described.